# My characters won't strafe or move left to right

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I even checked my project settings about horizontal and vertical. It is correct and it is set to WASD, but my character wont move or strafe from left to right.

I put my character set to animation though like he just walk straight with a lil curve here and there but that wont conflict with this script right?

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour {
     [SerializeField] float controlSpeed = 10f;

     void Update()
     {
         float horizontalThrow = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
         float VerticalThrow = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
         Debug.Log(horizontalThrow);
         Debug.Log(VerticalThrow);

         float xoffSet = horizontalThrow * Time.deltaTime * controlSpeed;
         float newXpos = transform.localPosition.x + xoffSet;

         transform.localPosition = new Vector3(newXpos, transform.localPosition.y, transform.localPosition.z);

    }
}
```

Comment: Looks good to me, have you checked the value of controlSpeed in the Editor ?

Answer (score 0):

try
`transform.localPosition += new Vector3(xoffSet, transform.localPosition.y, transform.localPosition.z);`, that is just adding the offset directly to the existing position of your player instead of computing the final value with newXPos. that seems a bit unnecessary.

Also, In your animator component on the player, make sure `Apply Root Motion` is not checked. applying root motion on an animator whilst trying to also move it externally generally causes issues like these, because their positions are being overridden by each other, causing conflict.